# How to create a domain entry to point to a website address

Tags: dns, web, active-directory, domain-driven-design

I am being told to add a domain entry to point to a specific web address. Could you please advise how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Edit the A(Address) record in your DNS registrator interface